# Getting GBP back from Bitcoin?

Tags: trading, transaction-fees, exchange-fees

I have a handful of BTC that thanks to the recent interest are now worth me trying to get back into GBP that I can spend.  I've done a little research, but the only methods of converting my BTC into GBP that I can spend seem to involve hefty fees.  What's the cheapest way of converting 4-5 BTC into GBP?

Comment: For small amounts you could be better off to buy some goods with it.
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade

Comment: i would be interested in taken them on. let me know. it will take some time for local businesses to get into BTC conversions.

Comment: I would also be interested in purchasing 1btc from you. Not an easy solution but worth noting - eBay users in the UK are willing to pay over-the-odds value wise for small denominations, which even after eBay fees works out at a greater profit than trading into an exchange. It's arduous though and up to you whether it is worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in London, you could go to the local meetup group and sell them directly http://www.meetup.com/London-bitcoin-meetup/ and there is also https://localbitcoins.com/ Both ways people can pay you in cash, with no fees.